# Почему пропадает рисунок если не скрыть консоль С++?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Разбираюсь с winApi и рисованием на окнах и столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда пытаюсь сделать рисунок на рабочем столе то он сразу же пропадает если я не свернул консоль, вот код:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false);
    HWND hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC dc = GetDC(hwnd);
    SelectObject(dc,GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
    SetDCBrushColor(dc,RGB(190,115,255));
    Rectangle(dc,10,10,110,100);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Вот с таким кодом все прекрасно получается, но стоит мне только убрать строку `ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false);`

То когда я запускаю программу рисунок появляется буквально на одну миллисекунду и тут же исчезает с рабочего стола. Объясните пожалуйста почему так происходит? как не скрытая консоль мешает рисовке?

Comment: У вас завершается работы программы. Каждое приложение с графическим интерфейсом имеет в своём роде "бесконечный" цикл обработки событий окна (и других устройств) и отображение этого на экран. У вас же такого цикла  нет. Попробуйте ради интереса обернуть рисование прямоугольника в бесконечный цикл.

Comment: @V31R Да так работает, только теперь у меня рисунок вообще не убирается))) как его убрать не подскажите?)

Comment: Прервите работу цикла.  Для подобного есть диспетчер задач, а внутри кода обрабатывайте события окна, можно ради эксперимента поставить счётчик на какой-нибудь миллион итераций

Comment: Рисовать следует на своем окне.